# Reorder custom field location on the Lead layout screen

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

When creating custom fields in Leads,

How can I reorder the location of the field on the Lead Layout page?

Salesforce is arranging everything alphabetically,

Does anyone know why?

Comment: You can modify the layout and reorder fields as you wish: [Customizing Page Layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_layoutcustomize.htm&language=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're in the order you create them, actually, but you can change this layout by going to Setup > Customize > Leads > Page Layouts, editing the appropriate layout, and saving. Professional Edition without custom profiles has but one layout, so you won't get an option to choose one to edit in that case.